# AVX-512 instructions library in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, x86, linker, avx512

I have a C++ library built in Visual Studio 2017 which uses AVX-512 intrinsics. I need to link the library to VS2008 C++ code. The library is used to extract lines from an image. All the intrinsic instructions are encapsulated within the library. VS2008 code passes in `char* data`, `LineSpec` (structure with 4 floats) and `char* result`, which gets filled with extracted lines.

I am unable to link the library due to error C1083: Cannot open include file: `immintrin.h`. I am also unable to build the library in VS2017 using VS2008 tool-set for the same reason.

The goal is to increase extraction speed with AVX-512 instructions while compiling the rest of the code with VS2008. I am new to intrinsics and mixing platforms. Do you have any suggestion on how to use the library in VS2008?

Comment: Build a DLL of the library using VS 2017. This DLL can be easily linked by VS 2008 (either dynamically or by providing .lib file) when you restrict the interface to basic data types.

Comment: Don't put `#include <immintrin.h>` in the header that users of the library need to include.  Make that private.  Obviously you need to compile the library itself with a modern compiler, but you should be able to statically link it.

Comment: If it is only a few functions called, manually align stack and all inputs before call, and vzeroupper after?

Answer (score 2):

You can't

To call a function that uses ymm registers the compilers need to emit instructions to prepare those according to the ABI. But AVX-512 didn't exist in 2008, thus there's no way for VS2008 to know about the ABI or AVX-512 instructions

And then when linking you also need to know about the instruction set to know which address to fix, although this might be easier to solve with the offset stored in the object code

In short you need to update the compiler instead of using a decade-old one

Comment: Solved the problem by removing visibility of all AVX routines from the library header and using a dynamic instead of statically linked library. DLL did not run into linker errors when called by VS2008. But thanks for the advise, I agree that we need to update to a new compiler :).